# Búsqueda en tabla excel de otra tabla excel con vba

Tags: excel, vba

estoy trabajando con vba y hago uso de la funcion `FIND` para rellenar una columna con valores que se encuentran en otra tabla al igual como se hiciera con la funcion `buscarv`.

```
Set h2 = Sheets("Kardex") 
filas = Hoja1.Cells(Hoja1.Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To filas
        descrip = Hoja1.Cells(i, 1).Value
        Set b2 = h2.Columns("A").Find(descrip) 

        If Not b2 Is Nothing Then                    
                    Hoja1.Cells(i, 13) = h2.Cells(b2.Row, "G")
        End If
Next i
```

El problema es:
Tengo en la hoja1 en la columna A valores del 1 al 1000 sin valores duplicados y al buscar valores digamos 25 y 250 en la hoja2 llamada **Kardex**, en el cual sólo está el valor de 250 entonces solo debería copiar el valor de la columna correspondiente para dicho valor, pero lo que hace es copiar los valores tanto para 25 y 250 es decir no hace una **búsqueda exacta**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El método `Find` tiene un parámetro llamado `LookAt` que especifica si lo que se busca (en tu caso, por ejemplo el valor `25`) tiene que ser coincidencia parcial (25 coincide con 25 y con 250) o exacta (25 solo coincide con 25).

Por defecto, este parámetro viene como `xlPart`, es decir, coincidencia parcial.

Prueba de la siguiente manera:

```
Set b2 = h2.Columns("A").Find(descrip, , , xlWhole)
```

Fuentes:

> [Método Range.Find
> (Excel)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)
>
> [Enumeración XlLookAt
> (Excel)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/excel.xllookat)